# Inno Setup Custom Installing Page

Tags: inno-setup

I am using browser control(Thanks to TLama for the Demo Example) to play some youtube videos during the installation. But in my case as soon as the installation finished, wpFinish page will be shown and video vanishes. Hence i need to create the finish button in the installing page and installation should exit only when i clicked finish button. Until that user can watch the video.

Thank you.